# Función que no me lea siempre el mismo archivo

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programita que me lee ficheros en trozos y tengo todo conseguido el unico problema qque tengo es que siempre me esta leyendo el mismo fichero y necesito que me vaya recorriendo el fichero igual que hace para generar los valores.

```
def conteo_caracteres(conteo):
    lista = []

    for i in conteo:
        lista.append(len(i))

    for a in lista:
        contador = 1
        # print(a)

        suma = lineas
        while suma < a:
            suma += lineas
            contador += 1
        contador = contador

        limit = math.ceil(a / contador)

        num = limit
        suma = 0
        list = []
        while suma < a:
            suma = suma + num
            list.append(suma)


        dictOfWords = {i: list[i] for i in range(0, len(list))}
        print(dictOfWords)

        u = 0
        for key, value in dictOfWords.items():
            inicio = u
            final = value
            que = i[inicio:final]
            print(que, key)
            u = value + 1
```

Comment: Hola Alfonso, mencionas que le problema es que siempre lee el mismo fichero, pero en el código no manejas ningún fichero explícitamente, ¿podrías aclarar ésto?

Comment: los ficheros los traigo en la llamada a la funcion ay estoy leyendo todos los ficheros